# Angular - Object is possibly 'null' in Dynamic FormArray

Tags: angular

I am using Angular-12 to implement Dynamic FormArray using Reactive Form. I have this code:

Component:

```js
updateContact() {
  this.contactInfoForm = this.fb.group({
    id: [''],
    current_residential_address: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(500)]],
    contacts: this.fb.array([
      this.addContactFormGroup()
    ])
  });
}

addContactFormGroup(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    phone_type_id: ['', Validators.required],
    phone_number: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15)]],
    is_primary_contact_number: ['']
  });
}

addContactButtonClick(): void {
  ( < FormArray > this.contactInfoForm.get('contacts')).push(this.addContactFormGroup());
}

get fc() {
  return this.contactInfoForm.controls;
};

contactValidate() {
  if (!this.contactInfoForm.valid) {
    this.contactInfoForm.markAllAsTouched();
    return;
  }
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.updateContact();
  this.loadAllParameters();
}

loadAllParameters() {
  this.employeeService.getEmployeeParameters().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.phonetypes = data.results.phonetypes;
    }
  );
}
```

HTML:

```html
<form [formGroup]="contactInfoForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="current_residential_address">Current Residential Address:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
        <textarea rows="2" formControlName="current_residential_address" name="description" type="text" placeholder="22, Alexander Close ..." class="form-control mb-3" required>
                              </textarea>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="fc.current_residential_address.touched && fc.current_residential_address.invalid">
        <div *ngIf="fc.current_residential_address.hasError('required')">
          <div class="text-danger">
            Current Residential Address is required!
          </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="fc.current_residential_address.hasError('minlength')">
          <div class="text-danger">
            Current Residential Address cannot be less than 2 characters!
          </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="fc.current_residential_address.hasError('maxlength')">
          <div class="text-danger">
            Current Residential Address cannot be more than 500 characters!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div formArrayName="contacts" class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let contact of contactInfoForm.get('contacts').controls">
      <div formGroupName="0" class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone_number">Phone Number:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <div class="input-group mb-4">
              <ngx-intl-tel-input [cssClass]="'form-control mb-4'" [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries" [enableAutoCountrySelect]="false" [enablePlaceholder]="true" [searchCountryFlag]="true" [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Iso2, SearchCountryField.Name]"
                [selectFirstCountry]="false" [selectedCountryISO]="CountryISO.Nigeria" [phoneValidation]="true" [separateDialCode]="true" name="phone_number" formControlName="phone_number">
              </ngx-intl-tel-input>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="fc.phone_number.touched && fc.phone_number.invalid">
            <div *ngIf="fc.phone_number.hasError('required')">
              <div class="text-danger">
                Phone Number is required!
              </div>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="fc.phone_number.hasError('validatePhoneNumber')">
              <div class="text-danger">
                Invalid Phone Number!
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone_type_id">Phone Type:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <ng-select [items]="phonetypes" [selectOnTab]="true" [searchable]="true" bindValue="id" bindLabel="type_name" placeholder="Select Phone Type" [multiple]="false" [clearable]="true" required formControlName="phone_type_id">
            </ng-select>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="fc.phone_type_id.touched && fc.phone_type_id.invalid">
            <div *ngIf="fc.phone_type_id.hasError('required')">
              <div class="text-danger">
                Phone Type is required!
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone_type_id">Is Primary Line?:</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck2">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i> Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" (click)="addContactButtonClick()"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add item</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="isLoading" class="btn btn-success" (click)="contactValidate()">
                      <span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                      <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have this error in the HTML, and got this highlighted:

> controls

in

```
<div formArrayName="contacts" class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let contact of contactInfoForm.get('contacts').controls">
```

How do I get that sorted out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following method in your .ts file to retrieve the FormArray. You need the extra casting to FormArray.

```
getContactsFormArray(): FormArray{
    return this.contactInfoForm.get('contacts') as FormArray;
  }
```

and then

```
<div formArrayName="contacts" class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let contact of getContactsFormArray().controls">
```